# how reference a key-> value if a key is from a regular expression in preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex

Having this array:

```
$arr['id']=150;
$arr['contenido']="un proyecto";
$arr['foto']="una foto";
```

This works very good

```
$text = 'estamos en el registro {id} cuyo contenido es {contenido} por lo que veremos su {foto}';
$text = preg_replace('/{(.*?)}/', '$1', $text);
echo $text;

//print:
//estamos en el registro id cuyo contenido es contenido por lo que veremos su foto
```

I understand that $1 y the value enclosed by { and } but I need replace with the value of array that match with the key. I trying this

```
$text2 ='estamos en el registro {id} cuyo contenido es {contenido} por lo que veremos su {foto}';

$text2 = preg_replace('/{(.*?)}/', $arr['$1'], $text2);
echo $text2;

//print
estamos en el registro  cuyo contenido es  por lo que veremos su
```

but this no print anythig in the pos of {key}, how I get impresed the array value referenced by the key y n {}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/{(.*?)}/',
    function (array $m) use ($arr) { return $arr[$m[1]]; },
    $text2
)
```

Comment: it still print "estamos en el registro  cuyo contenido es  por lo que veremos su "